# How to derive a relationship between the variables in R by using ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have tried to determine the relationship between the variable "RainTomorrow" and others by the code below. But, seems like the way I coded is not giving me the output. How do I determine the relation of RainTomorrow and all other variables?

```
rattle::weatherAUS  # to load the dataset into R

str(weather)
weather$Date <- as.Date(weather$Date)
weather$RainTomorrow <- as.factor(weather$RainTomorrow)

# exploring all the varibales
weather %>%
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_histogram()
```

Comment: The same code is giving me output

Answer (score 0):

`rattle::weatherAUS` merely prints the data to console. You need to run `weather <- rattle::weatherAUS`

After that everything will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use `facet_grid()` to show `RainTomorrow` in each row and other numeric variables in each column.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rattle)

# exploring all the varibales
weather %>%
  mutate(RainTomorrow = as.integer(RainTomorrow)) %>% 
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(RainTomorrow = weather$RainTomorrow) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-RainTomorrow, names_to = "name", values_to = "value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_grid(vars(RainTomorrow), vars(name), scales = "free") +
  theme_test()
```

Comment: I did follow your code but the graph values seem to overlap. Is it the same with you or the problem is from my end?

Comment: Is it possible that your plot panel is too small? I'm not so sure what you mean.

Comment: My panel is good enough to view the plots.

Comment: What do you mean "the graph values"?

Comment: The values on the x-axis are overlapping

Comment: So this has something to do with your plot panel limitation. You can save this image with large enough width to avoid the overlap.